# Database of non-isomorphic trees

Tags: co.combinatorics, trees, data-analysis, online-resources

As there are several free prime number databases, is there something similar for non-isomorphic trees?

Comment: Start one. You'll be the first!

Comment: @Will: Hardly the first.  Try http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/trees.html
In general they can be generated so fast that storing them seems pointless.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, good point. But see the (American edition) cover of Interesting Times, by Terry Pratchett:  Not tested on animals, you'll be the first!  http://www.amazon.com/Interesting-Times-Discworld-Terry-Pratchett/dp/0061056901#reader_0061056901

Comment: They grow faster.